# How can i create instance of foo class from response's json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, okhttp

I'am using okhttp to operate on api requests but i've no idea how to create instance of pojo class from JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gson/Jackson library to deserialise response. Consider the service you are calling returns below response

```
{
 "data": {"name": "Foo", "id": 1}
}
```

Then your POJO/models would look like

```
public class ServiceResponse {
   private Data data;
}

public class Data {
  private String name;
  private int id;
}
```

And your simple OkHttp client call is like

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Then you can deserialise response using Jackson like this

```
ServiceResponse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.body().string(), ServiceResponse.class)
```

Refer this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-json-response) for detailed explanation